# ASP.NET MVC: How to default to a page given certain condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a class called `PasswordChangeChecker.cs`that has a method that returns from the database whether or not a user has changed their password. The signature for that method is:

`public bool IsPasswordChangedFromInitial(string IdOfUser)`

where `IdOfUser` is the Id field from the Identity framework User. If it returns true, that means the change password page should not be displayed, otherwise, it should navigate to the change password form. Once the user successfully changes their password, the database flag gets set appropriately, and they should not be prompted for a password change again (unless manually forced to by an admin). How can I put this method in the `RouteConfig.cs` file, where currently I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

    namespace IdentityDevelopment
    {
        public class RouteConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
}
```

How can I add a conditional construct into the `defaults` parameter so I can use the `IsPasswordChangedFromInitial` method to decide whether or not to go to the password change page? That page is at `/Account/ChangePassword`.

**EDIT**

As per the comments, the appropriate action methods for my specific need are (I have omitted irrelevant code):

**Login post action:**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel details, string returnUrl)
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    AppUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(details.Name,
                        details.Password);
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        AppUser userByName = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(details.Name);
                        if(userByName == null)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //If this else is reached, it means the password entered is invalid.
                           //code for incrementing count of failed attempts and navigation to lock out page if needed

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(user.LockedOut)
                        {
                            //navigate to locked out page
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PasswordChangeChecker PassCheck = new PasswordChangeChecker();
                            string userId = user.Id.ToString();
                            bool proceed = PassCheck.IsPasswordChangedFromInitial(userId);

                            //Authorize the user
                            ClaimsIdentity ident = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                                                     DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                            ident.AddClaims(LocationClaimsProvider.GetClaims(ident));
                            ident.AddClaims(ClaimsRoles.CreateRolesFromClaims(ident));
                            AuthManager.SignOut();
                            AuthManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                            {
                                IsPersistent = false
                            }, ident);

                            //persist login into db code


                            if (proceed)
                            {

                                //reset failed logins count
                                return Redirect(returnUrl);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return ChangePassword();
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
                ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
                return View(details);
            }
```

**ChangePassword() get action:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
{
   return View();             
}
```

Somehow the view returned is the view in the `RouteConfig.cs` instead of the `ChangePassword.cshtml` page.
Thank you.

Comment: *Routing* is for (well...) routing. That is, matching a Url with a certain controller/action. What you're trying to accomplish (enforcing password policy) belongs more to the realms of *Authentication*. Why not check `IsPasswordChangedFromInitial()` upon login?

Comment: @haim770 I did try it from login, but I have spent ages trying to debug why it goes to the home screen instead of the change password page, that I decided to try this as a last resort.

Comment: You'll have to provide more code then. Are the controllers/actions you're trying to protect decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute? Is `AuthorizeFilter` globally registered?

Comment: @haim770 yes, the change password page is protected by `[Authorize]`, how can I check if the `AuthorizeFilter` is globally registered?

Comment: Usually it's in `GlobalFiltersConfig.cs`. But I guess you'll have to revise the question so it will reflect the actual question more appropriately. Please show your authentication controller/action and where you expect it to redirect to change-password page.

Comment: @haim770 I have added the appropriate methods for what I am trying to do. I think it would be good to know how to do what I asked in my original question too, in case of a case where there should be a page conditional routing for some other reason.

Comment: The reason that `return View()` in your `ChangePassword` is not rendering the correct view is because you're calling it *within the context* of the `Login` action (and when you're performing `return View()` without adding the view name, it will be determined automatically based on the `action` parameter in your current routing values, and what will be `Login` in your case). Either *redirect* to `ChangePassword` using `return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword")` or change `return View()` to `return View("ChangePassword")`

Comment: @haim770 thank you, that returns me to the change password page now.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with global action filters

you can make a [action filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470787(v=vs.98).aspx) with method

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (showChagePwPage)
    {
        //redirect to the change password page
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("ChangePassword", "Account");
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

and then adding it into global action filter by

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(yourFilterContext);
```

Comment: I did not try this, but thanks for the alternate idea.

Answer (score 1):

After several days of this hellish exercise similar to yours, where I was trying to route users at login, I realized that I wasn't going to be able to get the value of the UserId while in the login of the Account controller. I did some experimenting and came up with this approach that solved my problem.

I create an ActionResult in my Home controller and called it Purgatory (of course I renamed it to something more suitable once it proved functional). There, I stuffed all my login logic for routing the logged-in user to their respective page upon login.

Then, in the RedirectToLocal in Account controller, I changed the

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

to

```
return RedirectToAction("Purgatory", "Home");
```

So now when a user logs in, if the returnTo param isn't set to a particular page, the returnTo param will be null and when it gets to the RedirectToLocal, it'll drop to what used to be the redirect to the home page, which will now go into purgatory.

Comment: I also saw the Id was being returned null, but somehow the username was coming through, so I went ahead with that. But thanks for explaining your approach on how to deal with the missing Id.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good time to use an action filter, which you can apply globally or per controller/action.

Here's a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class VerifyPasswordChangedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("changepassword", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

                PasswordChangeChecker PassCheck = new PasswordChangeChecker();

                if (!PassCheck.IsPasswordChangedFromInitial(userName))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "account", action = "changepassword", area = string.Empty }));
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I would modify your `IsPasswordChangedFromInitial` method to simply use the authenticated user's username, rather than trying to figure out how to get access to a `UserManager` instance in an action filter. Otherwise, assuming you're using the OWIN-based ASP.NET Identity, add a claim to store that `user.Id` field when you create your `ClaimsIdentity`, so that you don't have to keep looking it up.

The outermost conditional handles the case of this being a global filter - without it, you would get an infinite redirect.

Comment: This was very helpful in what I wanted to achieve, as this was my next step to do once I got the redirection to the changpassword to work first.